# php regex string pattern match

Tags: php, regex

I have a string that can look in the following ways:

```
----4dfd650c9f65              match
-----473ffd650c9f65           match
-----473ffd650c9f65s3--       does not match
--473577f2hd650c9f65--        does not match
```

I would like to match if and only if starts with *at least two* `--` and ends on `\n` but does not ends with `--`

Thanks

Comment: These are individual strings? Not one huge block, correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
/^-{2,}[0-9A-Za-z]+$/
```